# Windows and Kali doesn't show up anyway. I just can enter ubuntu with problems

Tags: 14.04, windows, kali

I've got so much problem in my computers now but I can't define it what exactly is. One day I start my laptop and i saw a black screen that has command line. I thought I couldn't handle this and I prepare a usb stick that live os in it. I run grub-repair in live os and ubuntu grub was be solved.

Now I can't update or install from Ubuntu terminal. I can reach Windows and Kali files, bu I guess, not all of them. Now, I just want to stop that torture and I want to enter other OSs and back up everything.

I write a command in terminal sudo os-prober. That's the output

```
hata: `/dev/sda': Girdi/Çıktı hatası okuyamıyor.
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/raided-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/swaps-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/mounted-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/raided-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/swaps-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/mounted-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
Failed to probe /dev/sda4 for filesystem type
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/raided-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/swaps-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/mounted-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
Failed to probe /dev/sda5 for filesystem type
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/raided-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/swaps-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/mounted-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/raided-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/swaps-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/mounted-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
Failed to probe /dev/sda7 for filesystem type
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/raided-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/swaps-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/mounted-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
Failed to probe /dev/sda8 for filesystem type
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/raided-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/swaps-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
grep: /tmp/os-prober.GlqfGu/mounted-map: Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
```

hata = Error

Girdi/çıktı hatası okuyamıyor. = Cannot read input / output error.

Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok = No such file or directory.

Comment: Smells like possible hardware failure. Look up how to run a SMART test on that hard drive.

Comment: There is a warning in Smart Data, Disks: "Disk may fail soon." Everything is OK, except "read error rate". What should I do now? What does it mean?

Comment: It means exactly what it says: "Disk may fail soon" and the fact that you cannot use it anymore seems to indicate that your disk seems to be dying. You have demonstrated *hardware failure*. Ubuntu is not designed to run on broken, defective, or dying hardware, nor is Ubuntu designed to fix or workaround broken hardware. Your next step is to look up how to replace your dying hard drive.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks man. Apparently, I have to buy a new hdd or sdd. I guess, I can't get windows up also. Best choice for me, backing up all data is another hdd and changing hard disk in the laptop. Thanks for all your helps.